# How to trim an URL conditionally

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have the following code to trim an URL to check if a parameter exists. For example if the URL is `http://localhost:3000/page?name=jack?number=2000`, then the code should have `subString` as `2000`. There could be cases where the number parameter does not exist in the URL.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var subString = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('number=') + 7);

alert(subString);
alert(subString.length);

if (subString.length <= 0) {
    //logic here
}
```

This is not working as expected. For whatever reason, when the number parameter is not in the URL, subString becomes the full URL. However, when there is a number, then it works fine. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: try `var substring = location.search && location.search.match(/\d+/) `

Comment: Please look at this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way.  You should really parse the query string, do whatever it is you need to and re-build it from there.  Don't treat it like just any string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) `number=` in the present `URL`. if it returns `-1` means `number` parameter is not available in the `URL`.

**DEMO with number parameter :**

```js
var url = "http://localhost:3000/page?name=jack?number=2000";
if(url.indexOf('number=') != -1) {
var subString = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('number=') + 7);
alert(subString);
alert(subString.length);
} else {
  alert("no number param");
}
```

**DEMO without number parameter :**

```js
var url = "http://localhost:3000/page?name=jack";
if(url.indexOf('number=') != -1) {
var subString = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('number=') + 7);
alert(subString);
alert(subString.length);
} else {
  alert("no number param");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the method below, it meets your further fetching variables from querystring

**Function**

```
var getUrlParams = function()
        {
            var match,
            pl = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
            search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
            decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
            query = window.location.search.substring(1);

            var urlParams = {};
            while (match = search.exec(query))
                urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);

            return urlParams;
        }
```

**Usage**

```
var param = getUrlParams();
var number = param["number"];
```

Comment: if I just do `var number = param[number];`, I get `number is not defined`

Comment: I had a typo, fixed it now, btw you should insert the function above in your code and use it shown above.